Thinkpad X1 Carbon 12th Gen Ubuntu 22.04 Fingerprint Sensor not working well
I have been using my Thinkpad for a little bit now and I have noticed that the fingerprint sensor does not work most of the time. Could this be a driver problem? If so how would I fix it? I could only find drivers for Windows on the Lenovo Support site. I was wondering if there is something I can do to make it work better (or at all).

Linux has its own solution - there are several thread in this forum about it.
This is one of them.
To make a long story short. Open a terminal and type:
sudo apt install -y fprintd libpam-fprintd

Then you need to enroll your fingers:
sudo fprintd-enroll

Check if you need to enable pam-auth-update - but this you should understand before executing it.

I did all of that with no improvement. Any suggestions?

Not sure if this makes a difference but there is the fingerprint that I enrolled in the terminal and one that I setup in the system settings 'Privacy'

Well, be more verbose. There must be error messages. Describe what doesn't work when. journalctlmight display some messages as well
